# Why doesn't the spread operator add properties to my array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object

I'm working with a React useState variable. I have an array of objects that has 18 objects at this top level. I'm trying to update the object at the 14th index and then return the remaining objects after it. At first I was directly mutating the state by pushing my changes to it like so:

```
 setFormWizard(wizard => {
    wizard.controls[14].trash = true;
    return ({
      ...wizard,
      wizard: wizard.controls[14].group.push(...newSection.slice(0, 5)),
    });
  });
```

This works, but I'm told this isn't good practice because React may not catch the update if you push directly to the state in certain cases. So now I'm trying to use the spread operator instead.

What's happening is the first 14 objects are returning. The object I'm modifying is returning, but the rest of the objects that come after the 14th index are not returning. What am I doing wrong?

```
setFormWizard(wizard => {
  const subjectControls = wizard.controls[14]
  const groups = [...controls.group, ...subjectAddressCopy.slice(0, 5)]
  return ({
    ...wizard,
    controls: [
      ...wizard.controls.splice(0,14), // keep first 14 entries 
      {
        ...subjectControls,
        group: groups,
        trash: true
      } // modify the 15th entry
        ...wizard.controls.splice(15) // this doesn't return the remaining controls
      ],
  });
});
```

Comment: You probably want `slice`, not `splice`. They're completely different methods

Comment: `.splice(0,14)` *deletes* the first 14 items from the array. So, it's very likely that when you try to take the 15th item, it doesn't exist any more, if the array had less than 29 entries to begin with. Even then `.splice(15)` is guaranteed to return an empty array, since the return value of `.splice()` is an array of deleted items. But you don't pass a second parameter - the deletion count. Therefore, by default it would delete zero and return an array of zero length.

Comment: Another issue is that `push` returns the new length of the array, not the thing you pushed or the array.

Comment: What is `wizard`? What shape of object is `setFormWizard` expecting? Where are the magic numbers (14/15, 0, 5) in the function coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bcz `splice` changes in actual array you need to use `slice`

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.splice(0,2)
console.log('splice change in array so actual value of arr is :', arr)

const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
// it will take slice(start, end) but end not included in return value
const cutSection = arr1.slice(1, 3);
console.log('portion of array', cutSection)
```

Comment: So, it's a bit ironic, but when I console the object I see that this updated it, but it doesn't show the update in the state.

Comment: When i keep my initial code of pushing to the state the state shows my updates.

Comment: we solve your problem of not get value after `14` index, if you have any other prob than you have to provide minimal reproduction of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might've wanted to use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to return everything upwards from index 15.